# Google Cloud Platform: External IP Address isn't Accessible from Outside

Tags: tomcat, google-cloud-platform, jupyter-notebook, google-compute-engine, vpc

I have recently started working with "Google Cloud Platform". I basically want to use it for my data science project. I have successfully setup Project, VM Instance, Firewall Rules etc.

[image]

I have installed Jupyter Notebook which is running on port 8888 and I have installed Apache tomcat server. Now, I want to access these via static external IP address of my VM but these aren't accessible when I mention static external IP address.

I have verified external path,, project HTTP(s) traffic enabled, firewall rules for Apache tomcat and Jupyter Notebook added and Ping to that external IP address is also working. In the image below, all the firewall rules for jupyter notebook and tomcat can be seen:

[image]

I tried to access by the following ways:

- https://{static-external-ip}/
- https://{static-external-ip}:8080/
- https://{static-external-ip}:888/

Any help in this regard will be a great favor. Happy Learning!

**Update: November 10th, 2018**
I can access the servers using the following URLs:

- https://8080-dot-4783318-dot-devshell.appspot.com/ (Apache Tomcat)
- https://8888-dot-4783318-dot-devshell.appspot.com/ (Jupyter Notebook)

First these aren't accessible publicly (externally) and secondly issue while accessing the servers with static external IPs is still there.

Comment: Did you open port 8888 in your firewall rules explicitly? HTTP(s) and Tomcat / Jupyter are all HTTP servers and so probably all run on port 80 (or 443 for HTTP(s)) by default, so using custom port 8888 is probably your problem. You could either open up that port and access it at `http://{static-external-ip}:8888`, or you could restart the notebook on port 80 and then access it at `http://{static-external-ip}`.

Comment: @Dan thanks for your reply. Yes, as I mentioned in my question, I have already configured firewall rules and I have added picture as well in the actual question for you reference. And major issue is that tomcat server is also not accessible which is already running on the default port.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have done all steps for exposing a service to the outside, except I am guessing for one thing - Is Jupyter listening on loopback interface? Per [Jupyter's documentation](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html) -

`By default, a notebook server runs locally at 127.0.0.1:8888 and is accessible only from localhost. You may access the notebook server from the browser using http://127.0.0.1:8888.`

The documentation provides information on how to make it [accessible to the outside world](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html#notebook-public-server). In short, to access the service has to bind to on all interfaces (ips).

Comment: Thanks @Daniel-t for your response. But I already added these option while configuring it. I added these two lines regarding this: 1) Notebook.ip = "/*" and 2) notebook.allow_origin = "/*". P.S: added slash intentionally as alone esterik symbol was being disappeared.

Comment: So, I don't think that issue is with these configurations as I mentioned in my question as well that I tried same with simple Apache tomcat server as well and observed the same error. So, not being able to understand that what got missed :) I'm really screwing my head on this...

Comment: Can you post the output of this command - `netstat -tan |grep 8888` ?

Comment: I don't get any output after running this command. Neither error nor any response.

Comment: hmm, are you sure Jupyter is running on 8888? That command will show you any services listening on port 8888. Try this - `sudo netstat -talpn  | grep -i jupyter`

Comment: Sorry I'm running it on 8889 now. For command: netstat -tan |grep 8888 ==>
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8889            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::8889                 :::*                    LISTEN

Comment: Let us try ssh tunnel, you will create an ssh tunnel to port 8889 ( jupyter?) and then connect to it from your local browser. Try this `ssh -f -N -L 8889:localhost:8889 username@external_ip`  - Replace username and external_ip with the VM instances info, if the ssh is successful, start your browser and hit "http://localhost:8889"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183421/discussion-between-daniel-t-and-bilal-ahmed-yaseen).

Comment: sudo ssh -N -f -L localhost:8888:localhost:8889 bilalahmedpu@35.201.179.179 
The authenticity of host '35.201.179.179 (35.201.179.179)' can't be established. 
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:eFraJmrXeAWB3IeN0Rk/nWkiHCkm5YLzlGha0ASslic. 
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes 
Warning: Permanently added '35.201.179.179' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts. 
Permission denied (publickey).

Comment: After reading the [chat session](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183421/discussion-between-daniel-t-and-bilal-ahmed-yaseen) it appears that you were running your installation in Cloud Shell. As such your connection test to the VM were not successful. 

I would recommend posting this type of questions in [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com) as StackOverflow is for Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers.